# Laravel SPA Authentication with Vue JS 3

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, laravel-sanctum

I set up everything correctly in vue js application and also in laravel application. These are separately handled.

I set up in main.js

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.withXSRFToken = true;
```

But when user is logged in, it shows 401 status

I tried many solutions on stack and others but nothing helps me

I have separate domains `frontend.task.com` for `vuejs` and `backend.task.com` for `laravel`

I also set in `.env`

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.task.com
```

The token is generated but shows status 401

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything is set up correctly - you're making a request to `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` and the `/login` request is successful, you're not getting any `419` responses - your problem is most likely related to the sanctum's stateful domains list.

Open your `.env` and set:

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=frontend.task.com
```

Careful, if you somehow use any port, like frontend.task.com:5173, this will not work, you'll have to add the domain directly in the sanctum.php config file -> stateful array.

If it still does not work, open up the `EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful` middleware, go to the `fromFrontend` function and add a log statement as follows:

```
public static function fromFrontend($request)
{
    $domain = $request->headers->get('referer') ?: $request->headers->get('origin');

    if (is_null($domain)) {
        return false;
    }

    $domain = Str::replaceFirst('https://', '', $domain);
    $domain = Str::replaceFirst('http://', '', $domain);
    $domain = Str::endsWith($domain, '/') ? $domain : "{$domain}/";

    $stateful = array_filter(config('sanctum.stateful', []));

    Log::debug('stateful?', [$domain, $stateful]);

    return Str::is(Collection::make($stateful)->map(function ($uri) {
        return trim($uri).'/*';
    })->all(), $domain);
}
```

Then try again and check the logs. Make sure `$domain` is actually part of the `$stateful` array.

Hope it helps!